# Transform circuit with 3 CNOTs in one with limited interactions on the first qubit

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

[image]

Is it possible to translate the above circuit into an equivalent one where the number of interaction gates with the first qubit is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First, let's recall the **bridge-gate**, which is

[image]

Then now, using this fact, we have that

[image]

is **equivalent** to

[image]

which can be **simplified** to

[image]

**Therefore**,

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think it might be generalizable to any 3-qubit circuit?